# What does the hex address mean in ldd output?

Tags: linux, bash

For example:

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
      linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc3563000)
      libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f87e5459000)
```

What do "0x00007ffcc3563000" and "0x00007f87e5459000" mean here?

I have queried man page, according to the it:

> ldd displays the location of the matching object and the (hexadecimal) address at which it is loaded.

Does it mean the shared object's virtual address in the kernel space? But what if this shared object has not been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *are* loaded (if not before then certainly while running `ldd`), that's actually how `ldd` works.

The `ldd` program uses the dynamic linker `ld.so` to find ***and load*** the objects needed to satisfy dependencies.

This is described in the man-page for `ldd` along with a warning that you may want to heed about it possibly *executing* the program you give it under certain circumstances (and giving an alternative). Basically, don't use it on untrusted binaries.